# Auto-load B43 wifi card module in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, kernel-modules

I am using a Dell Vostro 1500 (looking to buy a new computer) and I have installed the wifi drivers with `b43-fwcutter` or whatever the actual name of it is, but you probably know what I'm talking about.

I am having a problem where I need to enable the wifi kernel module every time I boot my computer, using `sudo modprobe b43`.

How can I make this automatic?

To make it clear I have tried a couple of things beforehand without success:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-load-a-kernel-module-automatically-at-boot-time/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730096/how-to-autoload-a-kernel-module-in-gentoo-linux

I may not have tried all of these methods or may have done them incorrectly. So go ahead and advice any of these and I will try them again just to make sure. I'm pretty sure I have tried them correctly and they didn't work however. Again, not all of them.

Comment: you already have find the soultions, what have you add to your modprobe file?

Comment: @Kiwy all right. I will try all of them when I can and report back.

Comment: Both those sources are incorrect. Just use the [method in the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Loading)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried all of the methods on those links and also the one @jasonwryan put in his comment, which is direct to the Arch wiki. None of them worked.

I found this fishy and just started exploring. Found `/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-wl.conf` which contained the following line (among others):

```
blacklist b43
```

So it was getting removed from the list of things to load no matter what I tried. Removed it and it worked (FINALLY).

Thanks everyone for your help. :)

P.S.: Arch Wiki on black listing: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Blacklisting

Comment: You should have mentioned that you were not using Arch, but an Arch-derivative...

Comment: @jasonwryan You are right. I am using ArchBang (IIRC). I had forgotten about that because my original intentions were to use vanilla Arch. Now I know this is not an issue in vanilla. :)

Comment: Yes, Archbang makes all sorts of "convenient" configuration choices (like the one you found) for you...

Comment: @jasonwryan thank you very much for your help. I'll note in the future that I use ArchBang. :)